# Linux - SSH login attack and high swap usage

Tags: linux

On linux OS - Can SSH login attack(ssh root login failed attempts) cause orphaned serial console process and results in high swap usage and  running threads to swap space increasing swap memory usage/CPU usage over all..

process logs shows hundreds of serial console process hanging around and there has been many root log in failed  attempts .Does linux/Unix(by default) ran all the command in the initial login(all these login attempts are found be failed SSH root access attempt against my servers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your questing but consider installing something like fail2ban to reduce the load and risk of all these attempted logins.

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page